# Cucumber feature file - parsing to an object

Tags: java, object, cucumber

I was wondering if anyone knew a way to parse a cucumber feature file (without executing or anything) to a Feature object in Java?

Answer (score 1):

For one of the projects I was working on. I was required to parse the feature files into Java Object for further processing and usage. I created a mapper class (detailed above) and used the following code:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.yaml.YAMLFactory;
import gherkin.formatter.JSONFormatter;
import gherkin.parser.Parser;
import gherkin.util.FixJava;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

public Feature[] getFeatures(String filepath) throws Exception {

        //Step One: Parse feature into JSON using Gherkin
        String featureText = FixJava.readReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(filepath), "UTF-8"));
        StringBuilder json = new StringBuilder();
        JSONFormatter formatter = new JSONFormatter(json);
        Parser parser = new Parser(formatter);
        parser.parse(featureText, filepath, 0);
        formatter.done();
        formatter.close();

        //Step Two: Convert the Features to plain old java object, and return an array of features
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        return mapper.readValue(json.toString(), Feature[].class);
}
```

Here is Gist => https://gist.github.com/jatin-sethi/7c6f6a95a2e7dd0ea12fce105070aa40.